# Window background visible through textures

Tags: c++, opengl, blending

What can I try to solve this problem? In this example (see a screenshot below) I am using OpenGL 1.1 with deprecated functions like: glEnableClientState, glMatrixMode, glTexCoordPointer, and so on. Thanks in advance.

You can see the whole example code in this thread: https://community.khronos.org/t/window-background-visible-through-textures/109061

I draw with `DEPTH_TEST`:

```cpp
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

/* ... */

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Player
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, spriteTexture);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(playerBody->GetPosition().x * WORLD_SCALE,
                playerBody->GetPosition().y * WORLD_SCALE, 10.f);
glScalef(16.f, 16.f, 1.f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, drawingIndex, 4);

// Coin
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(178.f, 120.f, 10.f);
glScalef(16.f, 16.f, 1.f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 24, 4);

// Enemy
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(194.f, 184.f, 10.f);
glScalef(16.f, 16.f, 1.f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 20, 4);

// Background
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, backgroundTexture);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
glScalef(256.f, 216.f, 1.f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4);

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
```

Texture:

[image]

[image]

Various window background values to show that I have an alpha channel:

For `glClearColor(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);`

[image]

For `glClearColor(0.2f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 1.f);`

[image]

My Settings:

```cpp
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

```cpp
GLuint createTexture(char *path)
{
    int h_image, w_image, cnt;

    unsigned char *data = stbi_load(path, &w_image, &h_image, &cnt, 0);

    if (data == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed to load an image" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(-1);
    }

    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    {
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w_image, h_image, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    stbi_image_free(data);

    return texture;
}
```

Comment: Do not add the "solution" to the question. This makes the answer useless.

Comment: I've added some useful information that z-order matters

Comment: No. You must add solutions to an answer, but not in the question. You can add an additional answer to your own question. I already pointed out in my answer that the depth check discards fragments before they can be blended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Transparency is achieved with the alpha channel and [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) only works when the textures have an alpha channel. When the alpha channel of the transparent background is 0.0 and the alpha channel of the object is 1.0 then you can use the following blending function:

```cpp
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

How can the objects be blended with the background if there is no background? You have to draw the background before you draw the objects and you don't nee the depth test at all. You must draw the object after the background. Using the depth test, fragments are discarded before they can be blended. You have to disable the depth test and draw the objects backt to front.

To render the scene you have to

1. disable blending and disable the depth test

   ```cpp
   glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glDisable(GL_BLEND);
   ```
2. draw the background
3. enable blending

   ```cpp
   glEnable(GL_BLEND);
   glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
   ```
4. draw the objects in the scene

Comment: I've added screenshots to show that the texture has an alpha channel.

Comment: What is the drawing order? You need to draw the background and after the background you need to draw the objects and blend them with the background.

Comment: I've added a code to show that I draw with DEPTH_TEST.

Comment: Okay, I will try now

Comment: @8Observer8 How can the objects be blended with the background if there is no background? You have to draw the background before you draw the objects and you don't nee the depth test at all. I've added the suggestions to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! You solved my problem. The location on the z-axis also matters (see glTranslatef for Coin, Player and Enemy). I have added the code in the "solution" section

Comment: `you don't nee the depth test at all` -
Yes, I deleted the depth test and it still works without it. And it is better because I do not need to think about Z-axis

Answer (score 1):

> you don't nee the depth test at all

Yes, I removed the depth test and it still works without it. And it's better because I don't have to think about the z-axis for all sprites. I can just set the Z position for all objects to 0.

Just additional information to Rabbid76's solution about the depth test. Not only the drawing order plays a role, but also the location along the z-axis. For example, this is the correct location on the z-axis: z = 0 for background, z = 5 for coin, z = 10 for enemy and z = 15 for player:

```cpp
// Background
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, backgroundTexture);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
glScalef(256.f, 216.f, 1.f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, spriteTexture);

// Coin
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(178.f, 120.f, 5.f);
glScalef(16.f, 16.f, 1.f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 24, 4);

// Enemy
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(194.f, 184.f, 10.f);
glScalef(16.f, 16.f, 1.f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 20, 4);

// Player
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(playerBody->GetPosition().x * WORLD_SCALE,
                playerBody->GetPosition().y * WORLD_SCALE, 15.f);
glScalef(16.f, 16.f, 1.f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, drawingIndex, 4);

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
```

[image]

[image]

Wrong order on z-axis, for example: z = 15 for coin, z = 10 for enemy and z = 5 for player:

```cpp
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Background
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, backgroundTexture);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
glScalef(256.f, 216.f, 1.f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, spriteTexture);

// Coin
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(178.f, 120.f, 15.f);
glScalef(16.f, 16.f, 1.f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 24, 4);

// Enemy
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(194.f, 184.f, 10.f);
glScalef(16.f, 16.f, 1.f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 20, 4);

// Player
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(playerBody->GetPosition().x * WORLD_SCALE,
                playerBody->GetPosition().y * WORLD_SCALE, 5.f);
glScalef(16.f, 16.f, 1.f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, drawingIndex, 4);

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I don't see where the background is visible through a texture? If you are talking about the greenish background behind the coin and mario, just use vertices that actually create the shape of the sprite. However, one issue I might see with your code is that you aren't generating a mipmap for your texture. Before you run `glTexImage2D()`, make sure you generate a mipmap:

> `glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`

Either way, I recommend not using OpenGL 1.1 - it is very deprecated and modern OpenGL is much better.

Comment: Mipmapping has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I also use shaders. But this is a task that I do for a student. His teacher demands to use deprecated functions.